# Spring Boot MyBatis @MapperScan No Longer Functions as WAR

Tags: spring-boot, war, mybatis

**Description of Issue**

I have a `Spring Boot` `Java` application which uses `MyBatis` `Mappers` that talk to `DB2` through the use of `interfaces` with `XML`.

This set up works properly when running as a `Spring Boot` application in the `Eclipse IDE`. However, when I use `Mavan` to build the application as a `WAR` file, and deploy it on an external `Tomcat` server, suddenly I receive errors that my mappers cannot be found when the application deploys:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springmapper': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'thingTypes'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'otherthingtypes': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 

org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.myapplicaton.dao.MybatisMapper.selectByExample
```

I get the feeling that, when running as a `WAR`, the app is no longer scanning these `MyBatis` `mappers` as `mappers`. I must need to change some configuration, but I can't figure out what.

====================

**Current Configuration** (Works when running on `Eclipse IDE` as `Spring Boot` app)..

(1) All `MyBatis` `java` mappers in com.myapplicaton.dao have the `@Mapper` annotation:

```
package com.myapplicaton.dao;

@Mapper
public interface MybatisMapper {
   List<Thing> selectByExample(ThingExample example);
   //... 
}
```

(2) Added a `MapperScan` to the application startup..

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan({"com.myapplicaton.dao","com.myapplicaton.other.mappers"})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

(3) Use the `MyBatis` Mappers in `@Autowired` classes:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

    @Bean(name = "springmapper")
    @Scope(value = "singleton")
    public SpringMapper getSpringMapper() {
        return new SpringMapper();
    }

    @Bean(name = "thingTypes")
    @Scope(value = "singleton")
    public ThingTypes thingTypes() {
        return new ThingTypes();
    }
}
```

```
package com.myapplicaton.other.mappers;

public class SpringMapper {

    @Autowired
    ThingTypes thingTypes;

    //...
}
```

```
package com.myapplicaton.beans;

public class ThingTypes {
    @Autowired
    MybatisMapper mybatisMapper;

    //...
}
```

====================

**Question**

Why doesn't this work when deployed as a `WAR`?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474493/8814467 Let me know if works @Miss Kitty

Comment: @Aliy Hello! I saw this post earlier. However, I don't have a MybatisConfiguration which implements EnvironmentAware at all. When I tried it, EnvironmentAware forces you to implement a method called setEnvironment(Environment environment), and I have absolutely no idea what that environment is/should be.

When I try it with the environment method doing nothing, it doesn't appear to change anything one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after messing with this all day, I sort of have an answer.

**Firstly**, I had to remove two 'problem' beans I had which used `@PostConstruct` on an `init()` method which used an `@Autowired` `Mybatis` mapper. I don't know why it didn't like that, but I don't care because after I removed them, the application booted properly as a `WAR`.. mostly.

It used to do something like this:

```
package com.myapplicaton.beans;

public class ThingTypes {
    @Autowired
    MybatisMapper mybatisMapper;

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
    private void init() {
          mybatisMapper.selectByExample(example);
    }
}
```

**The second issue** I had was that the application could not find the `MyBatis` `mapper` `.xml` files in my `dao` package when deployed as a `WAR`. It was fine when run on Eclipse, as per usual.

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.myapplicaton.dao.MybatisMapper.selectByExample
```

I checked the `WAR` file, and lo and behold, the `.xml` files had been skipped by `Maven` and only the `Java` `class` files lived in that folder. I couldn't figure out how to unskip `.xml` files with `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, and I wasn't about to try to figure out another plugin, so I was able to beat the system as follows:

I created a set of folders in the `src/main/resources/` folder of the app with exactly the same folder structure as where the `.java` `interface` `mappers` were located. So, I created `src/main/resources/com/myapplication/dao`. I put all of the `.xml` files in there.

Upon checking the new WAR, the `.xml` files were placed into the same directory as the `java` `class` files, and `MyBatis` worked properly.

Hurrah.

Comment: Well done this might help others as well :) thanks for sharing